# How to change the matrix's element with incanter?

Tags: matrix, clojure, incanter

How to change a element in the matrix? According to Incanter document, the library is built on top of Clatrix. With Clatrix, set an element in the matrix with the command `(set A 1 2 0)`. Please comment how to set the element in incanter. Thank you.

```
(ns cljsl.optimization
  (:require [incanter.core :as i]
            [incanter.stats :as s]))

;; create a matrix  
cljsl.examples=> (def A (i/matrix [[0 1 2] [3 4 5]]))

cljsl.examples=> A
 A 2x3 matrix
 -------------
 0.00e+00  1.00e+00  2.00e+00 
 3.00e+00  4.00e+00  5.00e+00 

;; the view the item 
cljsl.examples=> (i/$ 0 0 A)
0.0

;; element can be set with Clatrix, unfortunately, it don't correct with Incanter.
cljsl.examples=> (cl/set A 1 2 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(require '[clojure.core.matrix :as m])

(m/mset! A 0 0 -1)
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask a question? What is the difference between with or without  (') in front of "["?

Comment: I got the error message "No implementation of method: :set-2d!". I am using [incanter "1.5.7"] with clojure "1.10.1", incanter 1.9.3 is incompatable with clojure "1.10.1", Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. After review the book `Clojure for Machine Learning` and `Clojure for Data Science`. Found procedures to fix the error.

1. adding the following dependency to the `project.clj` file.

   ```
   [clatrix "0.5.0"]
   ```
2. The namespace declaration

   ```
   (ns cljsl.optimization
    (:require [clatrix.core :as cl]
              [incanter.core :as i]
              [incanter.stats :as s]))
   ```
3. Testing

   ```
   cljsl.optimization=> (def A (i/matrix [[0 1 2] [3 4 5]]))
   #'cljsl.optimization/A
   cljsl.optimization=> A
   A 2x3 matrix
   -------------
   0.00e+00  1.00e+00  2.00e+00 
   3.00e+00  4.00e+00  5.00e+00

   ljsl.optimization=> (cl/set A 1 2 0)
   #object[org.jblas.DoubleMatrix 0x1c951881 "[0.000000, 1.000000, 2.000000; 3.000000, 4.000000, 0.000000]"]
   cljsl.optimization=> A
   A 2x3 matrix
   -------------
   0.00e+00  1.00e+00  2.00e+00 
   3.00e+00  4.00e+00  0.00e+00
   ```